# UART and internal clock on PIC18F4431

Tags: c, embedded, pic, mplab

I made a programm with a PIC18F4431 on MPLABX with XC8. It sends PWM according the value which it receives on the UART (it is DMX, 250000kbits/s). This programm works, it runs with an external clock (quartz of 10MHz).

Configuration bits :

```
// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HSPLL      // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (clock frequency = 4 x FOSC1))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Oscillator Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode disabled)
```

UART configuration :

```
void Config_UART1 (void)
{
    BAUDCTLbits.BRG16 = 0;  // Générateur 8 bits
    SPBRG = 9; // Vitesse de transmission 250kbits/seconde
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1; //Haute vitesse
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // Asynchronous mode
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // Serial port enabled
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 1; //Selects 9-bit reception
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Enables receiver
}
```

To improve my programm, I want to work with the internal clock (8MHz). I change my configuration bits and my UART configuration ; my programm doesn't work : do you know why?

Configuration bits :

```
    // CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = IRC      // Oscillator Selection bits (Internal oscillator block, CLKO function on RA6 and port function on RA7)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Oscillator Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode disabled)
```

Oscillator configuration :

```
void Config_Oscill (void)
{
    OSCCONbits.IDLEN = 0b0; // Run mode enabled; CPU core is clocked in power-managed modes
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0x7; // 8 MHz (8 MHz source drives clock directly)
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0x02; // Internal oscillator block (RC modes)
}
```

UART configuration :

```
void Config_UART1 (void)
{
    BAUDCTLbits.BRG16 = 0;  // Générateur 8 bits
    SPBRG = 1; // Vitesse de transmission 250kbits/seconde
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1; //Haute vitesse
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // Asynchronous mode
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // Serial port enabled
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 1; //Selects 9-bit reception
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Enables receiver
}
```

Comment: Internal oscillator usually has a bad accuracy, very bad compared to an external cristal. In your case with 250K baud  a minimal jitter of the base freq can put your RX out of baud tolerance. If I remember well PICs have INTOSC reg to calibrate the internal oscillator.

Comment: Take note that temperature will cause internal oscillator to shift its accuracy.

Comment: I know for the temperature. I don't understand because I mesure 8Mhz with my oscilloscope on the PIC.

Comment: I'm not getting you..

Comment: Your second code set the UART at 250kb/s, but your first code doesn't. Your FOSC is at 10MHz, not 40MHz, so you get 62.5kb/s. Also, what is your problem ? You don't say anything. Does the PIC start at all ? Do you get a signal on the UART ?

Comment: I use PLL in the first, so I have 40MHz. I haven't PWM on my output, so I think the handling of my UARTdoesn't occur.

Comment: You have 10MHz. It's even written in your code that `clock frequency = 4 x FOSC1` and your PIC doesn't support more than FOSC=10MHz in HS+PLL mode.

Comment: My first code works, and it is set for 250kb/s, this is not the problem.

Comment: Well, the PIC documentation clearly says that your FOSC is 10Mhz and your UART is 62.5kb/s. This means that, according to the documentation, you second code output the serial 4 times faster. If you are sure that the documentation is wrong, then we need more information, like what signal the UART actually outputs.

Comment: Have you problem on RX or TX. Sending and receiving break signal (start if packet) and spool data at 250K is different if you have a ?40MHz? or a 8MHz FOSC...

Comment: I just need to receive on the UART, and not send. On my first code, `#pragma config OSC = HSPLL      // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (clock frequency = 4 x FOSC1))`  so my clock frequency is 4 x 10MHz = 40MHz. After, with the calcul, I find SPBRG = 9 to have 250000kb/s. It is sure and verified. On my second code, `#pragma config OSC = IRCIO      // Oscillator Selection bits (Internal oscillator block, port function on RA6 and port function on RA7)`  so my clock frequency is 8MHz . After, with the calcul, I find SPBRG = 1 to have 250000kb/s.

Comment: I have a lot of experience on DMX. Slave devices usually must have DMA to spool data from UART at 250K. I think your PIC does not have DMAs and then: are you sure that 8MHz are enough to spool your RX and continue doing other things, such as change the PWM duty cycle?

Comment: Did you actually verify the 250kb/s with an oscilloscope ? The formula is given as `((FOSC/Desired Baud Rate)/16) – 1`, and your FOSC is 10MHz. You are confusing with the clock (FCY), which is 40MHz. FOSC is for OSCillator Frenquency, not clock.

Comment: I'm sorry but my calculs are rights and it works with a quartz of 10MHz. I did programm which works in reception of DMX, so I don't understand. Yes it's enough, I saw a programm in assembler which works.

Comment: C and assembler are very different in performance. With assembler you can tune all your code. How are you testing your communication? QLC+, custom software, a real master console?

Comment: About the baud rate, it would be faster if you just tried your 2nd code with `BRGH=7`. If it still doesn't work, then there really is a mistake in the datasheet. In any case, it would help to know how you test your comm (what is on the other end), like LPs said.